# Why does QDialog::exec() move the window to the left upper corner of the screen after QMessageBox::warning(...)?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following sequence of actions:

```
//MyDialog inherits QDialog and I constuct this dialog with parent = 0
MyDialog* myDialog = new MyDialog(); 
myDialog->exec();
myDialog->Return();
myDialog->exec();
```

During first call of exec the dialog is shown at the center of the screen. Then function `Return` shows `QMessageBox::warning` (with parent = 0). Then second `exec` call shows the dialog at the left upper corner of the screen (I want it be at the center of the screen again). If `Return` function doesn't show `QMessageBox::warning`, the second `exec` call shows the dialog at the center. Why does `QMessageBox` spoil this behaviour of `QDialog::exec`? And how can I fix it in my program? (I don't want to create this dialog again, I just want to show it second time)

I have noticed that with bigger dialog window size it works perfect...

**Update:** Actually I can replace `myDialog->Return();` with `QMessageBox::warning(0, "title", "message");` and I will be having the same problem. So the next code

```
MyDialog* myDialog = new MyDialog(); 
myDialog->exec();
QMessageBox::warning(0, "title", "message");
myDialog->exec();
```

contains the same problem. In other words, there is problem with `QDialog::exec` and `QMessageBox`, but not with `myDialog->Return();`

P.S. I use Debian with Gnome 3 and Qt 5.2. I created MyDialog in QtCreator using Add New... -> Qt Designer Form Class -> Dialog with buttons right

Comment: To show a dialog, you should be using a `show()` method, and not `exec()`. `exec()` and similar event-loop-reentering methods (like `waitForXxx`) are a source of subtle errors and are completely unnecessary with the sole exception of `QDrag` (at the moment, it's really a bug).

Comment: Post the code of the Return() method.

Comment: @Vince  Instead of myDialog->Return(); I can write QMessageBox::warning(0, "title", "message"); and it will give the same result

Comment: @KubaOber `show()` doesn't block execution flow of a function which opens this dialog. This function should get results of this dialog and process them. Therefore I can't use `show()`

Comment: Is it necessary to have all parents at NULL? It is good practice to set the parent appropriately for many reasons. As a test, set the parents for myDialog and for your QMessageBox to the current application's window.

Comment: You can and should use `show`. You get the results of the dialog by hooking up its signals. Most likely, you need to connect to the `accepted()` signal. In Qt 5 with C++11, it doesn't require a separate slot method - you can write continuation code in a lambda. Asynchronous code breaks up monolithic functions into blocks that each execute in their own state. Conceptually, pre-dialog and post-dialog are two states.

Comment: @Vince if parent isn't NULL, a dialog (`MyDialog` or `QMessageBox`) will be shown at the center of parent window, but I would like it be at the center of the screen. Nevertheless, `parent = this` for both `MyDialog` and `QMessageBox` hasn't solved the problem